# Estimating position and orientation of a camera

Tags: optics, coordinate-systems, geometric-optics

Consider a camera sensor.
The pixels form a matrix.
Now consider the case where you have a horizontal slit in front of the camera so that only one row of the sensor is illuminated.
In reality rays of light are coming into the sensor but let us employ the principle of reversability of light and imagine a ray going out from each pixel.
Let us introduce a local coordinate system $\\{x,y,z\\}$ in the camera so that the ray from the central pixel of this row is pointing in the $-\hat{z}$ direction and all rays are in the yz plane.

The direction vector of the ray from the i'th pixel in this row becomes:
$$
\vec{dir}_i = [0, sin(\psi_i), -cos(\psi_i)]
$$
where $\psi_i$ is the angle between the i'th ray and the central ray.

Now consider the scenario where this camera is looking down on a target placed on a table and there is another coordinate system centered in the table: $\\{X,Y,Z\\}$:

[image]

The position of the target in the $\\{X,Y,Z\\}$ coordinate system is known: $(X_T,Y_T,Z_T=0)$, as is the angle of the ray from the camera that "observes" the target: $\psi_T$.

Unfortunately the position of the camera in the table coordinate system: $(X_C,Y_C,Z_C)$ is not known.

Further the axes of the camera coordinate system were intended to align with the axes of the table coordinate system. Unfortunately this is not possible to achieve in practice.
The result is that the direction vector of a ray in the basis of the table coordinate system, $\vec{DIR}$, is rotated relative to the direction vector of a ray in the basis of the camera coordinate system, $\vec{dir}$:

$$
\vec{DIR} = R * \vec{dir}
$$
where R is an unknown but close to identity 3x3 rotation matrix.

A point (X,Y,Z) along a ray is given by:
$$
(X,Y,Z) = (XC,YC,ZC) + s * \vec{DIR}  
$$
where $0 <= s$.

The ray intersect the target at Z=0:
$$
0 = ZC + s * DIR_Z
$$
where $DIR_Z$ is the z component of the $\vec{DIR}$.
Solve this for s:
$$
s = -\frac{ZC}{DIR_Z}
$$

Which gives us the X and Y coordinate of the intersection of the ray with the target:
$$
X_T = XC -\frac{DIR_X}{DIR_Z}ZC = XC -\frac{R12sin\psi-R13cos\psi}{R32sin\psi-R33cos\psi}ZC 
$$
$$
Y_T = YC -\frac{DIR_Y}{DIR_Z}ZC = YC - \frac{R22sin\psi-R23cos\psi}{R32sin\psi-R33cos\psi}ZC 
$$

Let us assume a position $(X_C,Y_C,Z_C)$ and orientation $R$ of the camera.
Find the error between the calculated and the actual target position:

$$
E = (XC -\frac{DIR_X}{DIR_Z}ZC - X_T)^2+(YC -\frac{DIR_Y}{DIR_Z}ZC - Y_T)^2 
$$
Repeat this procedure for N targets:
$$
SE = \frac{1}{N}\Sigma_{i=1}^N E_i 
$$

I can use gradient descent to minimize this sum and find an estimate of the position $(X_C,Y_C,Z_C)$ and the orientation $R$ of the camera. I understand how to do this.
I use [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula in matrix form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html) to express R.

The full expression for E can be found by running the following python code:

```
from sympy import *

XC, YC, ZC, theta, omega_x, omega_y, omega_z, psi, XT, YT = symbols('XC, YC, ZC, theta, omega_x, omega_y, omega_z, psi, XT, YT')

# Find rotation matrix, R, by Rodrigues formulae:
K = Matrix([[0, -omega_z, omega_y],[omega_z, 0, -omega_x], [-omega_y, omega_x, 0]])
R = eye(3) + sin(theta)*K + (1 - cos(theta))*K*K

DIR_X = R[0,1] * sin(psi) - R[0,2] * cos(psi)
DIR_Y = R[1,1] * sin(psi) - R[1,2] * cos(psi)
DIR_Z = R[2,1] * sin(psi) - R[2,2] * cos(psi)

DX = XC - DIR_X/DIR_Z*ZC - XT
DY = YC - DIR_Y/DIR_Z*ZC - YT

E = (DX**2 + DY**2)
```

I minimize the sum of this expression over N targets using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` with the constraint:
$$
\omega_x^2+\omega_y^2+\omega_z^2=1
$$
However is such a local minima also the global minima or may there be other more optimal solutions I will not find using gradient descent?

I would think that the local minima is also the global minima. But how can I "prove" this?